# Specified child has already a parent error

Tags: android

I am getting this error

> The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView()
>   on the child's parent first

This is the code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.categorylayout);

    LinearLayout main = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
    View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.categoryeditor, main, true);
    main.addView(view);
}
```

I'm getting this error because I'm passing `true` here:

```
inflate(R.layout.categoryeditor, main, true);
```

My Question:

`The specified child already has a parent` Where is the parent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.categoryeditor, main,true);
```

you are providing already the parent through the last two parameters. Passing `true` will tell Android to add the inflated view to `main`. So you can get rid of

```
  main.addView(view);
```

Also be aware that in your case the returned `View` is not the inflated one but its parent

Comment: 1.So the `true` at the last means that `main` is parent view and the `view` holds the parent ? Right

2. If the last parameter is `false`, then the view is not a parent view ? Right ?

Comment: `add it manually to main` Sorry could you please let me know what should I add ?

Comment: yes sorry. If you pass `false` as third parameter you have to call `main.addView(view);`

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.camera_fragment, main, true);
```

With

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.camera_fragment, main, false);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. But I really like to know what is the `parent` as per my code. It's been answered anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Your main view is parent. In this case your last parameter tell to attach to parent

```
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.categoryeditor, main,true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just read this documentation of that method

**Parameters:**
**resource ID** for an XML layout resource to load (e.g., R.layout.main_page)

**root** Optional view to be the parent of the generated hierarchy (if attachToRoot is true), or else simply an object that provides a set of LayoutParams values for root of the returned hierarchy (if attachToRoot is false.)

**attachToRoot** Whether the inflated hierarchy should be attached to the root parameter? If false, root is only used to create the correct subclass of LayoutParams for the root view in the XML.